# Preventing SQL injections in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-injection

I want to double check to make sure that this is preventing the injections correctly.

I have old code that uses a GridView (written by someone else a long, long time ago) in ASP .NET 3.5.

In the .aspx page (the GridView uses this datasource):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsUserTables" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Main %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [MyTable] WHERE [tableID] = @tableID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="tableid" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>        
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Does this prevent injections on tableId?

The code behind has this:

```
protected void sdsUserTables_Deleting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@tableId"].Value = myTableId;
}
```

Comment: Given that `tableID` is being passed as a parameter, I would suspect you would be safe.  I am curious to know though, how/where is the `tableID` being set?  It is a textbox?  A drop-down list?  A variable set in the code-behind...?

Comment: Its set in the code-behind. What happens tho if I had a parameter like: <asp:Parameter Name="searchBox" Type="String" />?

Comment: please post the code-behind that references, `tableID`.

Comment: its been updated. i tested on my machine with say if I switched id for something like a search value and passed it as a string, it didn't drop my table, which is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the case of the example you gave above, you are definitely safe.  It's always a best practice to sanitize your inputs.

Assuming that you have a form (of some type) with a textbox on it, that doesn't have a limit to the amount of text that can be typed in it (this could be potentially *very* bad).

Here is an example:

```
sqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter();
sqlParam.ParameterName = "@testParam";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testParam", textBox1.Text);
```

In the example above, once again assuming your textbox is unbound, the fact that you are stuffing the potentially malicious string into a parameter *prevents* the raw data from having an ill-effect on your table(s)/database(s).

Answer (score 1):

yes, you're using a variable and it's type is declared, those two factors will prevent a SQL injection attack.

See...
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/113/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ASP.NET

You can do the exact same thing by making your sql code into a stored procedure and passing a variable into that.

Comment: What if the parameter where a string like a search that a user typed in?

Comment: I might've worded that incorrectly, it's the Type="" that matters, as in specify what kind of parameter it is.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks ok to me to prevent a SQL injection attack:

- you are using a `<asp:Parameter>` tag for your SQL query. By this way, it will not be a part of the SQL command and will be sent to the SQL server as a parameter: this is the right way, regardless its type.
- the SQL command and the Connection String in the `<asp:SqlDataSource>` tag will be embedded to the assembly: it will not be available to the user nor visible in the page. So it cannot be tampered.

If you want to enforce protection against SQL injection in general:

Ensure that the `[validateRequest][1]` parameter of your pages is set to "true":

```
// This parameter is normally set to "true" by default in the machine.config file
<pages validateRequest="true" />
```

- Also there is a good habit that consists in validating **all** user inputs, and limiting input length to the necessary amount of characters.

For example:

```
// assuming myTableId is a string

try
{
    int i = int.Parse(myTableId)
    e.Command.Parameters["@tableId"].Value = i;
}
catch
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Table Id should be an integer");
}
```

If your user inputs are strings, there is no need to check for every SQL keywords if you use parameters.